# Find intersection between a 3D mesh and a line given by a sequence of point, using python

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, intersection

i have a 3D mesh (.vtk file) and a curve expressed as a sequence of points. I want to find the intersection point/points between the curve and the mesh. Does anyone know ho to something like that using python??

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.